# Mongo pipeline projection on sub array

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following document:

```
{
    id: "myId",
    boundedPlan: {
        plannedWeeks: [
            0 : {
                weekStartDate: date
                weekEndDate: date
                plannedDays: []
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    unboundedPlan: {
        plannedWeeks: [
            0 : {
                weekStartDate: date
                weekEndDate: date
                plannedDays: []
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

This plan represent some number of weeks in the future. The plan has a bounded or unbounded plan .
(I have the same structure on two different fields, because in the code they correspond to two different classes with different behavior).

I now have to do the following query.

"Get the current plan week given a date"

I wrote the following pipeline:

```
[
    { "$match" : { "ownerId" : "defaultOwnerId"}},
    { "$project" : { 
        "boundedPlan" : 1, 
        "unboundedPlan" : 1, 
        "plannedWeeks" : { 
            "$cond" : { 
                "if" : { "$ne" : ["$boundedPlan", null]}, "then" : "$boundedPlan.plannedWeeks", 
                "else" : "$unboundedPlan.plannedWeeks"}
            }
        }
    }, 
    { "$match" : { 
        "boundedPlan.plannedWeeks" : { 
            "$elemMatch" : { "weekStart" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2021-03-10T00:00:00Z"}}, "weekEnd" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2021-03-10T00:00:00Z"}}}}, 
        "$or" : [{ 
            "unboundedPlan.plannedWeeks" : { 
                "$elemMatch" : { "weekStart" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2021-03-10T00:00:00Z"}}, "weekEnd" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2021-03-10T00:00:00Z"}}}}
        }]}
    }
]
```

The problem is the following:

- knowing that Im operating over a plan with an unbounded plan and explicitly setting the second match :

```
"$match" : { 
    "unboundedPlan.plannedWeeks" : { 
        "$elemMatch" : { "weekStart" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2021-03-10T00:00:00Z"}}, "weekEnd" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2021-03-10T00:00:00Z"}}}}, 
}
```

works.

- of course I dont know if the plan is from the unbounded or bounded field, so I tried to add the or operator, which causes no selection at all.

Is there something Im missing?
(working with spring data mongo)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out... I was using the OrOperator class from spring data mongo wrongly:

```
new Criteria("field1").orOperator(new Criteria("field2"))
```

is not the same as

```
new Criteria().orOperator(new Criteria("field1"), new Criteria("field2")
```